# Weird behaviour when filling a nested numpy array with `np.nan`

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with a nested dtype:

```
dt = np.dtype([('e', '<f8'), ('n', '<i8'), ('pos', '<f8', (3,))])
arr = np.zeros(5, dtype=dt)

array([(0.0, 0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), (0.0, 0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       (0.0, 0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), (0.0, 0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       (0.0, 0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
      dtype=[('e', '<f8'), ('n', '<i8'), ('pos', '<f8', (3,))])
```

and I'm trying to fill the entire array with `np.nan`:

```
arr[:] = np.nan
```

However, this does not work as expected:

```
array([(nan, -9223372036854775808, [nan, nan, nan]),
       (nan, -9223372036854775808, [nan, nan, nan]),
       (nan, -9223372036854775808, [nan, nan, nan]),
       (nan, -9223372036854775808, [nan, nan, nan]),
       (nan, -9223372036854775808, [nan, nan, nan])],
      dtype=[('e', '<f8'), ('n', '<i8'), ('pos', '<f8', (3,))])
```

The second column here is obviously *not* `nan`.

Any idea how I can work around this issue?

Comment: Well the `dtype` is `i8` and `NaN` cannot be represented by `int` `dtype` so it looks like all that happens is it's being set to some unitialised value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second column *can't* be nan.  It has an integer type.  There is no nan representation for integers.

The value -9223372036854775808 is -2**63, i.e. the most negative 64 bit signed integer.